# transfer file via html5/websocket via wifi

Tags: javascript, html

I hope to transfer files between two pc,
There are many tools, but I prefer to use html5/socket to transfer files via wifi.
Is it possible?

Comment: If this is just a tool that you're looking for you can check [NitroShare](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/nitroshare-cross-platform-tool-for-sharing-files-across-a-local-network.html).
But then your question has nothing to do on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is possible without using any server side technologies like PHP or native application. 
You can pass on data with some header info to server which subsequently redirect your data to another devices/pcs.

Answer (score 0):

It is still under RFC but it is a good solution to send files peer to peer directly without server interaction. That is HTML5 Datachannel API.

Here are some useful references.

http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html#rtcdatachannel

http://www.webrtc.org/faq-recent-topics

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/WebRTC-hits-Firefox-Android-and-iOS

Demos

https://webrtc-demos.appspot.com/html/dc1.html

http://mozilla.github.com/webrtc-landing/data_test.html